# SLURM sbatch multiple parent jobs in parallel, each with multiple child jobs

Tags: parallel-processing, process, subprocess, parent-child, slurm

I want to run a fortran code called `orbits_01` on SLURM. I want to run multiple jobs simultaneously (i.e. parallelize over multiple cores). After running multiple jobs, each `orbits_01` program will call another executable called `optimizer`, and the `optimizer` will constantly call another Python script called `relax.py`. When I submitted the jobs to SLURM by `sbatch python main1.py`, the jobs failed to even call the `optimizer`. However, the whole scheme works fine when I ran locally. The local process status is shown below:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
shuha    39395  0.0  0.0 161540  3064 ?        S    Oct22   0:19 sshd: shuha@pts/72
shuha    39396  0.0  0.0 118252  5020 pts/72   Ss   Oct22   0:11  \_ -bash
shuha    32351  0.3  0.0 318648 27840 pts/72   S    02:08   0:00      \_ python3 main1.py
shuha    32968  0.0  0.0 149404  1920 pts/72   R+   02:10   0:00      \_ ps uxf
shuha    32446  0.0  0.0  10636  1392 pts/72   S    02:08   0:00 ../orbits_01.x
shuha    32951  0.0  0.0 113472  1472 pts/72   S    02:10   0:00  \_ sh -c ./optimizer >& log
shuha    32954  0.0  0.0 1716076 1376 pts/72   S    02:10   0:00      \_ ./optimizer
shuha    32955  0.0  0.0 113472  1472 pts/72   S    02:10   0:00          \_ sh -c python relax.py > relax.out
shuha    32956 99.6  0.0 749900 101944 pts/72  R    02:10   0:02              \_ python relax.py
shuha    32410  0.0  0.0  10636  1388 pts/72   S    02:08   0:00 ../orbits_01.x
shuha    32963  0.0  0.0 113472  1472 pts/72   S    02:10   0:00  \_ sh -c ./optimizer >& log
shuha    32964  0.0  0.0 1716076 1376 pts/72   S    02:10   0:00      \_ ./optimizer
shuha    32965  0.0  0.0 113472  1472 pts/72   S    02:10   0:00          \_ sh -c python relax.py > relax.out
shuha    32966  149  0.0 760316 111992 pts/72  R    02:10   0:01              \_ python relax.py
shuha    32372  0.0  0.0  10636  1388 pts/72   S    02:08   0:00 ../orbits_01.x
shuha    32949  0.0  0.0 113472  1472 pts/72   S    02:10   0:00  \_ sh -c ./optimizer >& log
shuha    32950  0.0  0.0 1716076 1376 pts/72   S    02:10   0:00      \_ ./optimizer
shuha    32952  0.0  0.0 113472  1472 pts/72   S    02:10   0:00          \_ sh -c python relax.py > relax.out
shuha    32953  100  0.0 749892 101936 pts/72  R    02:10   0:03              \_ python relax.py
```

I have a main Python script called `main1.py`, which does a for loop to run multiple `orbits_01` jobs at the same time. Then the main script will wait for all jobs to finish. Here 3 parent `orbits_01` jobs are running in parallel, and each parent job has multiple child jobs. The heavy computations are done by the python code `relax.py`, so each job should be able to run only using one core. I want to know what is the best way to submit and parallelize multiple parent jobs with multiple child jobs over all cores in one node on SLURM?

Comment: How are jobs submitted? With a submission script or with a Python package?

Comment: The jobs are submitted by simply submitting a Python script ```main1.py```, which creates multiple directories and calls ```os.system('./orbits_01.x < input.dat &')``` in each of them.